# Enumerate array of enum cases with filter

Tags: swift, enums

Is it possible to enumerate an array of Enum cases with contained values while filtering them in the same line?

Right now I'm doing

```
let modes = [FilterMode]()
for mode in modes {
    if case .categories(let data) = mode {}
}
```

What I'd like to do is something like this

```
for mode in modes where case .categories(let data) = mode {}
```

Or something like that. Is that currently possible in Swift 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use pattern matching in the `where` clause, but you can
use `for` with a `case` pattern (since Swift 2):

```
for case .categories(let data) in modes {
    // ... use `data` ...
}
```

This can also be written as

```
for case let .categories(data) in modes { ... }
```